# Can I return my XBOX 360 Slim for a new one?

Tags: xbox-360

I purchased a new XBOX 360 slim from Amazon about 2 months ago.

It has started to freeze while I am using it.  I am not sure what to do, and to be frank I just want it to work.  (If I wanted to troubleshoot issues I would play games on my PC.)

Is it too late to return it?  Can I send it to Microsoft as defective?  Can I get a new one or my $$ back (to buy a new one).

---

In case you are interested here is the details of what has happened:

I have really enjoyed having my xbox, though I really only played one game (Oblivion) plus a few arcade games.

I recently decided to branch out to a new game (Force Unleashed) and it messed up my XBOX.  I ended up having to delete my system cache to get it to work.  I played it and liked it.

But now I wanted to go back to Oblivion and my Save Games in Oblivion will not work (it freezes while loading).

My Arcade Game Peggle has now frozen too.

Grrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote the amazon [refund policy](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=15015711):

> Amazon.com does not accept returns of the following items:
>
> - Items that are classified as hazardous materials or use flammable liquids or gases
> - Computer laptops, desktops, and Kindle more than 30 days after delivery
> - Any product missing the serial number or UPC
> - Downloadable software products
> - Gift cards
> - Pay As You Go (or prepaid) phone cards
> - Prepaid game cards (World of Warcraft, Xbox 360 Live, Wii Points, etc.)
> - Items purchased from sellers other than Amazon.com
> - Some Jewelry orders (Learn more)
> - Some Health & Personal Care items (Learn more)
> - Grocery products and Gourmet gift baskets cannot be returned; however, Amazon.com will issue a full refund for damaged products sold by Amazon.com

In this context your Xbox falls under `Computer laptops and desktops`

Now you can try Microsoft [Directly](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/hardware/warranty/warranty/ProductWarranty360s.aspx):

> "Xbox 360 S" means a new Xbox 360 S console purchased from an authorized retailer.

and

> "Warranty Period" for Xbox 360 S, means 1 year from the date You purchased the Xbox 360 S from an authorized retailer; and for Accessories, means 90 days from the date You purchased the Accessory from an authorized retailer.

For reference, Amazon is an "Authorized Retailer"

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're in the US for now.

The Xbox 360 Slim has a 1 year warranty, for which the details can be read on the [Xbox Support Site](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/hardware/warranty/warranty/ProductWarranty360s.aspx)

You probaly want to contact Microsoft, explaining the problem, and see what they offer.